# What is the value of $x$ in this equation using logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithms and I need to find out the value(s) of $x$ in the below equation, preferably by logarithms.

$$x^{\sqrt{x}}  = (\sqrt{x})^x$$

**Edit:**

What I had already done before asking this question is: I tried taking logarithm on both sides and got 4 as a solution.

But I need two solutions of this equation.
Which is the other solution? How can it be got in a good way?

Comment: @Travis is this still off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x>0$. Taking the log it is equivalent to
$$
\sqrt{x} \log x = x \log\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2} x \log x.
$$
Note that $x=1$ is a solution. Otherwise $\sqrt{x}\log x \neq 0$. Simplify $\sqrt{x}\log x$ hence
$$
1=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x} \implies x=4.
$$
Therefore all solutions are $\{1,4\}$.

Comment: Which implies two solutions: $x=4$ or $x=1$.

Comment: Arguably $0$ may also be a solution as the right limit of both expressions is $1$ as $x \to 0^+$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1$ is a solution

It is $$x^{x^\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{x}{2}}$$so $$x^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{x}{2}$$Taking log $$\frac{1}{2}\log x=\log x-\log 2$$$$\log x=2\log 2$$$$\log x =\log 2^2$$Taking antilog $$x=2^2$$$$x=4$$So$$x=1,4$$

Comment: Yes I missed that